# How to use the value of another field to make a sql query for default values in a field in Oracle Apex form?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page where admin can assign roles to a user. There are two fields. The first one is where the admin select a user that he/she wants to assign a role to. The second one is the role field which displays all the roles available. If the user as already been assigned roles, I want those roles in the checkbox to be checked. So, In the "Default" options for the roles checkbox I entered a SQL Query returning Colon Delimited values which is given bellow:

```
SELECT ROLE_ID FROM USER_ROLE WHERE USER_ID = :P24_USER_ID;
```

":P24_USER_ID" returns the id of the selected user in the form. For this to work I also set "P24_USER_ID" as "Parent Item" inside "Cascading List Of Values" for the checkbox.

After doing this, Whenever I selected a user in the form, the roles checkbox reloads, and then displays and error with no error message. When I went to debug the page I saw the bellow error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting '*Session State Protection*' value to '*Unrestricted*' under Security section of *P24_USER_ID*